# Safari Reader font-size control like popover

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, popover

Safari has a nice popover that is used for controlling the font size. I'm talking about that one:

[image]

It's pretty nice, and my question is - how to implement something exactly like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many projects in github about popoverview, such as this https://github.com/takashisite/TSPopover 
One way to implement this is to add a transparent view that takes up the whole screen so that when I touch outside the popover content, it'll dismiss. And the rest you need to do is just add some subviews to your transparent view.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Really, If you want to use a popover then you can see this code [PopOver Link](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tspopover)

Or you can simply create a `UIView` containing 2 buttons , let this `UIView` rollout an animation whenever the `UIButton` on the bar is clicked and so on and so forth. Let me know for further queries :)